Expo-updates failing to run android build on windows
After installing and configuring expo-updates my expo app fails to build for android with the following error:
> Task :expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\WINDOWS\sqlite-3.36.0-93068ff4-a0a7-44a0-bc91-2fc763079ab2-sqlitejdbc.dll.lck (Access is denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:184)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:210)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:366)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:68)
        at androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier.<clinit>(DatabaseVerifier.kt:70)
        at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:82)
        at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:61)
        at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:79)
        at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep$process$databases$1$1.invoke(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:75)
        at androidx.room.processor.Context.collectLogs(Context.kt:149)
        at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep.process(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:75)
        at androidx.room.DatabaseProcessingStep.process(DatabaseProcessingStep.kt:42)
        at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:122)
        at androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(JavacBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:71)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:310)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:256)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:54)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:48)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:96)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:65)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.lambda$run$0(WorkerAction.java:135)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:127)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

> Task :expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

It seems odd to me that the lock file for sqlite is created in the windows folder, perhaps suggesting a configuration issue but I'm unable to find what's causing it. I've deleting the android folder/ gradle cache, changing the jdk and java tmpdir, none of which have worked.
Any ideas would be really appreciated

I hope this can help you.
I had the same issue and I just skipped this step and it's seems to be ok.
 ./gradlew assembleDebug -x :expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin

I don't know if you already have solved this problem by another way, but if yes, tell me what you did.
--------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------
My friend told me that he had the same issue and solved it downgrading the Java Version. Apparently the Java 17 hadn't this error.

Yeah you’re right I actually solved this after posting on GitHub. Turns out I was using JDK 18 instead of 17

@OliB great news! Please mark my answer as correct here and upvote <3. This can help someone in the future.

Turns out I was using JDK 18 instead of 17 as recommended by the expo docs. See this GitHub thread
